# UEFI LoadImage from Memory

Tags: uefi, efi

I am looking at using Bootservices function LoadImage to load a UEFI application image from memory. Function parameters are:

```
typedef
EFI_STATUS
LoadImage (
  IN BOOLEAN BootPolicy,
  IN EFI_HANDLE ParentImageHandle,
  IN EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL *DevicePath,
  IN VOID *SourceBuffer OPTIONAL,
  IN UINTN SourceSize,
  OUT EFI_HANDLE *ImageHandle
  );
```

Where I am allowed to provide a sourcebuffer that is already populated with the PE/COFF image to load. I am currently using sourcebuffer, and have prepopulated the buffer with a valid PE/COFF files contents. I pass that in under SourceBuffer and set DevicePath to Null. I receive the error "`EFI_LOAD_ERROR  Image was not loaded because the image format was corrupt or not understood`."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the information about the memory buffer as a device path - in the `DevicePath` argument.

Have a look through chapter 9 *Device Path Protocol* in the UEFI 2.5 specification (from [the UEFI forum](http://www.uefi.org/)). Especially 9.3.2.3 *Memory Mapped Device Path*.

You should load the entire file just as is is - no picking apart of sections required.

For an example, you can have a look at [the GRUB arm64 Linux loader](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/grub-core/loader/arm64/linux.c?id=7a210304ebfd6d704b4fc08fe496a0c417441879#n249), which does just this.

Comment: This was part of my problem. I updated my description with new information if you have any more insight i'd really appreciate it

Comment: From the point of view of maintaining a useful reference database, would it not be better to revert to the original question and raise the follow-on issue as a new one?

Comment: good idea, reverting. and asked new question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317566/uefi-loadimage-hangs