# Starting image from memory

Tags: c, uefi

I have a problem Loading and starting image from memory.
This is the code:

```
    UINT8 *Buffer;
    
    typedef struct
    {
        MEMMAP_DEVICE_PATH Node1;
        EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL End;
    } MEMORY_DEVICE_PATH;
    
    STATIC CONST MEMORY_DEVICE_PATH mMemoryDevicePathTemplate =
        {
            {
                {
                    HARDWARE_DEVICE_PATH,
                    HW_MEMMAP_DP,
                    {
                        (UINT8)(sizeof(MEMMAP_DEVICE_PATH)),
                        (UINT8)((sizeof(MEMMAP_DEVICE_PATH)) >> 8),
                    },
                }, // Header
                0, // StartingAddress (set at runtime)
                0  // EndingAddress   (set at runtime)
            },     // Node1
            {
                END_DEVICE_PATH_TYPE,
                END_ENTIRE_DEVICE_PATH_SUBTYPE,
                {sizeof(EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL), 0}} // End
    };
    
    MEMORY_DEVICE_PATH BufferDevicePath = mMemoryDevicePathTemplate;

    BufferDevicePath.Node1.StartingAddress = (EFI_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS)(UINTN)Buffer;
    BufferDevicePath.Node1.EndingAddress = (EFI_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS)(UINTN)Buffer + BufferSize;

    Prnt("Loading Image...");
    Status = gBS->LoadImage(
        TRUE,
        gImageHandle,
        (EFI_DEVICE_PATH *)&BufferDevicePath,
        Buffer,
        BufferSize,
        &ImageHandle);
    if (!EFI_ERROR(Status))
    {
            Status = gBS->StartImage (ImageHandle, NULL, NULL);
            if (EFI_ERROR(Status))
            {
                Prnt("Error Starting image ... Status=%08x", Status);
            }
    } 
    else {
          Prnt("Error Loading image ... Status=%08x", Status);
    }
```

The image verified to be fine by loading it (not from memory) with UEFI Shell using `load`.
However in this case there are no errors, The image seems to be started but the machine is stuck, there is black screen with white cursor on the upper left screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the MemoryType field in the MEMMAP_DEVICE_PATH structure.

```
///
/// Memory Mapped Device Path.
///
typedef struct {
  EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL        Header;
  ///
  /// EFI_MEMORY_TYPE
  ///
  UINT32                          MemoryType;
  ///
  /// Starting Memory Address.
  ///
  EFI_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS            StartingAddress;
  ///
  /// Ending Memory Address.
  ///
  EFI_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS            EndingAddress;
} MEMMAP_DEVICE_PATH;
```

With your code it is set to 0 (EfiReservedMemoryType), set it to 1 (EfiLoaderCode).

By the way there was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317566/uefi-loadimage-hangs), maybe the solution there can help you too.

Comment: I've changed followed your suggestion, and also changed `{sizeof(EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL), 0}}` // End` to `{(UINT8)sizeof(EFI_DEVICE_PATH), (UINT8)(sizeof(EFI_DEVICE_PATH)>> 8)}} // End`, It is still stuck.

Comment: Can you share a complete program that reproduces your problem, especially with the part where you load the other program into memory?

Comment: Your solution worked, I had problems with it at start.